# How do I deal with the RLException error that occurred during roslaunch?

Tags: c, ros

roslaunch throws RLException

Hello, I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Usi):

I followed all instruction in the tutorial, including installing the requested packages, until section 2.5

Then, when I type the following `oncommandomand` line,

```
roslaunch testbot_description testbot.launch
```

I get the following error:

> RLException: [testbot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [testbot_description] nor is [testbot_description] a launch file name
>   The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I have no clue what is going on here. Could anyone help me in fixing it?

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(find testbot_description)/urdf/testbot.urdf" />
    <arg name="gui" default="True" />
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(arg model)" />
    <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher"/>
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
</launch>
```

> RLException: [testbot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [testbot_description] nor is [testbot_description] a launch file name
>   The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Comment: It probably can't find the file. You can roslaunch it by name-path: `roslaunch ~/path/to/file/testbot_description/launch/testbot.launch`. Normally, you would have a workspace, such as `catkin_ws/src`, where the package would be under src `catkin_ws/src/testbot_description`. After compiling once `cd catkin_ws && catkin_make`, there should be a `catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` file. You have to source this file, `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. This should look familiar, you also have/had to `source /opt/ros/<ros_version>/setup.bash`

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have not sourced the already sourced (`source /opt/ros/MY_ROS_VERSION/setup.bash`) and compiled (`catkin_make`) ROS. In your ROS project folder, run

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

before you `roslaunch testbot_description testbot.launch` .
See also [roslaunch: [ ] is neither a launch file in package [ ] nor is [ ] a launch file name](https://answers.ros.org/question/143496/roslaunch-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-nor-is-a-launch-file-name/?answer=143501#post-id-143501).

Comment: I was having the same kind of problem with :
RLException: [turtlebot3_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot3_gazebo] - and solved by going to my catkin_ws directory and just running --> source devel/setup.bash

Answer (score 0):

Check if roscore is running by checking if the following command returns '/rosout'

```
rostopic list
```

If it returns the message

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
```

run

```
roscore
```